# Unable to get selective column names on Laravel Eloquent Nested Eager Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a Product Model with a following relationship:

```
public function recommendedPricing()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RecommendedPricing::class);
}
```

The Recommended Pricing Model is:

```
protected $fillable = [ 'sku_id', 'unit_type_id', 'base_price', 'min_billable_qty', 'max_billable_qty', 'discount_method'];
protected $with = ['bands'];
public function bands()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\RecommendedPricingBand');
}
```

The Recommended Pricing Band Model is like:

```
protected $fillable = ['sku_id','recommended_pricing_id','start','end','percent_change','fixed_price'];
```

Now In my Controller I am doing this:

```
Product::where('id', $product->id)->with(['recommendedPricing', 'recommendedPricing.bands'])->get();
```

which gives the entire result. But I want selected columns from both Recommended Pricing and Recommended Pricing Band. So, I tried this:

```
Product::where('id', $product->id)->with(['recommendedPricing:id, base_price, discount_method', 'recommendedPricing.bands:id, percent_change, fixed_price'])->get();
```

But this always results in an error.

My question: Is there any better approach or way to fetch the correct result for this kind of a nested relationship scenario?

Comment: Try `with(['recommendedPricing' => function($query) { $query->select('......`

Answer (score 0):

When eager loading particular fields you can't have spaces. I usually do a seperate with line for each relationship. I don't think you need the array either. And you always have to get the id first, which you have already :) hope this works...

```
->with('recommendedPricing:id,base_price,discount_method')
->with('recommendedPricing.bands:id,percent_change,fixed_price')
```